# Segmentation fault implementing quicksort in C

Tags: c, sorting, quicksort

I am trying to execute the Quick Sort code mentioned in the book *Data Structures Using C* by Reema Thareja.

The issue is that I cannot get the sorted array as output. Instead, when I add the elements in the array, the output screen disappears, and on running the code again I get the following:

[image: Output]

I am using the Turbo C++ Version: 3.2 Compiler

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
void quicksort(int arr[],int l,int r);
void main()
{
    int arr[10],l,r,i,n;
    printf("Enter Array size: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter Elements: ");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }
    quicksort(arr,0,n-1);
    printf("The Sorted Array is: ");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d",arr[i]);
    }
    getch();
}
int partition(int arr[],int l,int r)
{
    int left,right,temp,loc,flag;
    loc=left=l;
    right=r;
    flag=0;
    while(flag!=1)
    {
        while((arr[loc]<=arr[right]) && loc!=right)
        {
            right--;
        }
        if(loc==right)
        {
            flag=1;
        }
        else if(arr[loc]>arr[right])
        {
            temp=arr[loc];
            arr[loc]=arr[right];
            arr[right]=temp;
            loc=right;
        }
        if(flag!=1)
        {
            while((arr[loc]>=arr[left])&& (loc!=left))
            {
                left++;
            }
            if(loc==left)
            {
                flag=1;
            }
            else if(arr[loc]<arr[left])
            {
                temp=arr[loc];
                arr[loc]=arr[left];
                arr[left]=temp;
                loc=left;
            }
        }
    }
    return loc;
}
void quicksort(int arr[],int l,int r)
{
    int loc;
    if(l!=r)
    {
        loc=partition(arr,l,r);
        quicksort(arr,l,loc-1);
        quicksort(arr,loc+1,r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Time to use a debugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this function:

```
void quicksort(int arr[], int l, int r)
{
    int loc;
    if(l!=r)
    {
        loc=partition(arr,l,r);
        quicksort(arr,l,loc-1);
        quicksort(arr,loc+1,r);
    }
}
```

Here, our base case is `l==r`. But if we add a print statement (and some spacing)

```
void quicksort(int arr[], int l, int r)
{
    if (l != r)
    {
        printf("left: %d, right: %d\n", l, r);
        fflush(stdout);
      //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        int loc = partition(arr, l, r);
        quicksort(arr, l, loc - 1);
        quicksort(arr, loc + 1, r);
    }
}
```

and call it with

```
int arr[] = {4, 8, 1, 4, 5, 1, 8, 5, 7};
int arr_len = 9;
quicksort(arr, 0, arr_len - 1);
```

we get the following output:

```
left: 0, right: 8
left: 0, right: 1
left: 0, right: -1
exited, segmentation fault
```

Whoops: `left` was 0 and `right` was -1 and we called `partition(arr, 0, -1);` which immediately does an out of bounds memory access with the statement `arr[right]` => `arr[-1]`.

`if (l < r)` was probably the intent here:

```
void quicksort(int arr[], int l, int r)
{
    if (l < r)
    {
        int loc = partition(arr, l, r);
        quicksort(arr, l, loc - 1);
        quicksort(arr, loc + 1, r);
    }
}
```

which enables us to correctly establish the base case for recursion.

---

Beyond this bug, I recommend using space between operators, selecting meaningful names and avoiding unnecessary variables. An example of this is the beginning of the `partition` function. As written, it's:

```
int partition(int arr[],int l,int r)
{
    int left,right,temp,loc,flag;
    loc=left=l;
    right=r;
    flag=0;
// ...
```

But `l` and `r` are just being reassigned to `left` and `right` and then go unused for the remainder of the function. Writing it like:

```
int partition(int arr[], int left, int right)
{
    int temp;
    int loc = left;
    int flag = 0;
// ...
```

is clearer, but even here, we should move `tmp` (used for swaps) out to a separate function or at least scope it to the block where it's used to avoid stale value bugs. We should `#include <stdbool.h>` because that's what `int flag` actually is (or use early returns to eliminate the variable altogether) and improve the `loc` variable name (it's actually the pivot we're partitioning the integers on):

```
int partition(int arr[], int left, int right)
{
    int pivot = left;
    bool flag = false; // or remove this completely in favor of `return`
// ...
```

This is much cleaner.

Also, `void main` should be `int main` and use an explicit `return 0`. I recommend using a modern compiler and development environment and turning on all warnings:

```
gcc quicksort.c -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O2 -std=c99 -pedantic
```

This reveals unused variables in `main`, among other things, and generally reduces pain points.

Also, I recommend reading [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) which will give you the tools (both conceptual and software) necessary to walk through and reason about programs to localize errors.